# Generating random numbers array in Java

Tags: java, arrays

I'm working on a code that should generate an array with a length of 100 and then separates numbers form the array to:

1. Numbers that are multiples of 4.
2. Numbers that are not multiples of 4.

Below is my code, however, I'm getting a weird output (lots of zeros). How can I identify the problem?

```java
public class Assignment8 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Defined array to hold the values
        int[] randomValueArray = new int[100];
        int[] mod4ValueArray = new int[100];
        int[] nonMod4ValueArray = new int[100];

        // Initiate the randomValue Array
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
            // Generate a random number from the range 1 to 100
            int randomValue = (int) (Math.random() * 100 + 1);
            randomValueArray[i] = randomValue;
        }

        // Pass the array to the class method to separate mod4
        // value and non mod4 value from the randomized array
        mod4ValueArray = isMod4(randomValueArray);
        nonMod4ValueArray = isNonMod4(randomValueArray);

        // Print out the two result arrays
        System.out.println("Randomly generated numbers that are multiples of four: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < mod4ValueArray.length; ++i) {
            System.out.println(mod4ValueArray[i]);
        }
        System.out.println("Randomly generated numbers that are not multiples of four: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < nonMod4ValueArray.length; ++i) {
            System.out.println(nonMod4ValueArray[i]);
        }
    }

    // Mod4 Checker Method
    public static int[] isMod4(int[] array) {
        int[] resultArray = new int[array.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; ++i) {
            int itemValue = array[i];
            if ((array[i] % 4) == 0) {
                resultArray[i] = itemValue;
            }
        }
        return resultArray;
    }

    // Non Mod 4 Checker Method
    public static int[] isNonMod4(int[] array) {
        int[] resultArray = new int[array.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; ++i) {
            int itemValue = array[i];
            if ((itemValue % 4) != 0) {
                resultArray[i] = itemValue;
            }
        }
        return resultArray;
    }
}
```

Comment: All three arrays you create have 100 elements. You take 100 elements and spread them out over two other 100-element arrays. By definition at least one of those arrays will not be fully written (and unless you hit an unbelievably unlikely case, *both* arrays will not be fully written to). Array values that you've not written anything else to will have the default value (`0` for `int`). Also you instantiate the filtered arrays twice: once in your `main` and once in your dedicated methods, you can leave out the first one.

Comment: The number at `array[i]` doesn't necessarily belong at index `i` in the result.  You should keep a separate index for the result, advancing it only when you copy a number to the result.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
int[] randomValueArray = new Random().ints(100, 1, 101).toArray();
int[] mod4ValueArray = IntStream.of(randomValueArray).filter(i -> i % 4 == 0).toArray();
int[] nonMod4ValueArray = IntStream.of(randomValueArray).filter(i -> i % 4 != 0).toArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
new Random().ints(100, 1, 100).filter(n -> n % 4 == 0).toArray();
new Random().ints(100, 1, 100).filter(n -> n % 4 != 0).toArray();
```

Answer (score -2):

Java 8 Stream-esque solution:

```
Map<Boolean, int[]> map = new Random().ints(10, 1, 100)
    .mapToObj(i -> i)
    .collect(partitioningBy(i -> i % 4 == 0, collectingAndThen(toList(), list -> list.stream()
        .mapToInt(i -> i)
        .toArray()
    )));
```

This pulls 100 random integers from 1 to 100, then boxes all `int`s to `Integer`s, then partitions by whether the number is dividable by 4. Then, the resulting `List<Integer>` is converted to an `int[]`.

However, I think a plain old for loop is better. The only difficulty you have, is that you don't know how large each array will get. So at the end, you'll need to resize the arrays.

```
int[] fourMods = new int[100];
int[] nonFourMods = new int[100];
int fourModsCardinality = 0;
int nonFourModsCardinality = 0;

Random random = new Random();
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    int num = random.nextInt(100) + 1;
    if (num % 4 == 0) {
        fourMods[fourModsCardinality] = num;
        fourModsCardinality++;
    }
    else {
        nonFourMods[fourModsCardinality] = num;
        nonFourModsCardinality++;
    }
}
```